# app is too slow when adding multiple horizontal recycler view in a vertical recycler view

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to build a fragment that have a vertical list and its content is multiple recycler view. The application acts OK when there is just one horizontal recycler view. But when I'm trying to add more than 5 recycler views, it takes about 6 seconds to build the fragment. What is the best solution to have multiple horizontal list in a vertical list?
Consider that I'm trying to build a list like what shop-style android application has on its home page.

Comment: Did you use static ViewHolder for Recyclerview or listview ?

Comment: Multiple recyclerviews causes a memory leak.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to add it phongvan.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using threads, see the sample code below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //Load the recycleviews here
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: The problem is that updating ui needs to run just on UI thread.